# &lt and &gt issue with a sql statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm relatively new to sql and xml but have an application report generator that will generate the sql for queries that are very complex (to me anyway) and I try and cut and paste then to sql server. I just cant seem to get this one to work. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Select distinct a.IncidentID,  IsNull(i.CompName,'') As 'CompanyName' , IsNull(l.UserDefined2,'') As 'SalesStageDesc' , IsNull(l.UserDefined6,'') As 'UserDefined6' , IsNull(l.UserDefined1,'') As 'SalesTypeDesc' , IsNull(g.ContactName,'') As 'User' 
From tblIncident a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblCompany i with (nolock) ON a.CompanyID = i.CompanyID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblIncidentUtilityCross l with (nolock) ON a.IncidentID = l.IncidentIDx 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (select a.ContactName, b.IncidentID from tblContact a JOIN tblIncidentContact b ON a.ContactID = b.ContactID where (b.contacttypeid = 4 or b.ContactTypeID = 3)) g ON a.IncidentID = g.IncidentID &lt;IncidentHierarchy&gt; 
Where a.noreportdisplay !=1
```

if I comment out the &lt and keep the where clause it runs but I get the wrong answer. If someone could tell me what to do with that code it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL statements, you need to use the actual character `<` not the HTML entity `&lt;`, and `>` for `&gt`.  If you are executing this statement in a web form, you need to decode the entity into the actual character representation.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I did substitute the < and the > but I get an incorrect syntax error at the <

Comment: I'm just trying to put this into a sql query on the server.

Comment: `ON a.IncidentID = g.IncidentID <IncidentHierarchy>` is not valid syntax.  you might try `ON a.IncidentID = g.IncidentID as IncidentHierarchy`